# Change password in ORACLE from SQL Server via linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, change-password

I have an Oracle database connected to a SQL Server. The connection works correctly, but unfortunately, I don't know the password used for that connection. Now I need to change the password in Oracle.

Is it a good idea to run something like

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([oracle], '
     ALTER USER OracleUser IDENTIFIED BY pswd;
     SELECT 1 FROM DUAl')
```

Or maybe, is there another solution?

**UPD**
My query ends with error

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oracle" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d9580b8-c335-4344-8691-32d56a39b700/oracle-user-password-change-via-linked-server-with-sql-server-2005?forum=sqldatabaseengine - maybe this will work, never tried it.

Comment: surely a better idea would be to log onto the Oracle database with a user who has the privilege to change passwords, DBA role as an example, and work from there?

Comment: Thank you Robert. EXEC('...') AT [oracle] works for me. This query caused error `Server ‘oracle′ is not configured for RPC for a Linked Server`, but I altered linked server according to [this article](http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=120). And now I'm stumped with an oracle error `ORA-28221: REPLACE not specified`. It seems I need to call the oracle administrator.

Comment: You need to specify the old password. (Unless this is the first time you set the password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for changing password in Oracle from SQL Server via linked server is

```
EXEC ('ALTER USER OracleUser IDENTIFIED BY new_password REPLACE old_password') AT [oracle]
```